# How to use autocomplete to add brackets in java project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

Is it possible autocomplete in `Eclipse` Java project. Something like I type:

```
public static void clr()
```

then press something and get:

```
public static void clr()
{
}
```

`Alt+/` not working in this case.

Comment: Just type `{` + Enter?

Comment: You want to type 99.99% and let eclipse complete it with two curly brackets and line breaks? Sounds strange to me. What you can do is type `clr` and `ctrl + space` and let it generate a private method which you have to modify to `public static`.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I don't think you will get any shorter than just typing <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Alternatively, you could use the template for `public_static_method`, i.e. start typing `pub...`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, select the template (just press down once and then Enter), type in the method's return type and name and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to get straight to the body.

You can also go to *Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates* to adapt that template to your own needs (give it a shorter name, or move the `{` to a separate line) or define your own ones.